Rtree installation in python can't be imported
I downloaded and installed spatialindex from github, then pip install Rtree version 1.30, which is already visible in the site-packages directory, but can't import Rtree
enter image description here
There is no error when compiling and installing spatialindex, I tried to pip uninstall Rtree after installing spatialindex and then re-pip intsall Rtree, but I still can't import Rtree.

Try this py -m pip install Rtree --upgrade
